# php class Cannot use object of type User as array

Tags: php, fatal-error

I have a user class to get all user data, I tried to show a particular user's email but have error with `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type User as array in C:\...`, please advise.

**class:**

```
class User{

    public function get_user_info($user_id, $mysqli){
        if(empty($user_id)) {
            return null;
        }

        $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id='".$user_id."' LIMIT 1");

        if($sql->num_rows > 0){
            $row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
            return $row;
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

**call email:**

```
include('classes/user.php');

$user = new User;
$user->get_user_info($user_id, $mysqli);

echo 'email: '.$user['user_email'];
```

Comment: You need to instantiate $mysqli before using it on User class.

Comment: ok, I have initiate $mysqli, but now i get error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type User as array in C:\..`

Comment: please update the code in ur question so that every one can see what it is upto.

Comment: but $mysqli in $user->get_user_info($user_id, $mysqli); may be does not have that so u may need to instantiate it before calling the method.

Comment: in fact I had include header file with mysqli connection `$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);`, the new error is not related to mysqli i think.

Comment: ah you have error here echo 'email: '.$user['user_email']; change this to $data = $user->get_user_info($user_id, $mysqli); and then echo 'email: '.$data['user_email'];

Comment: error is gone, but data not shown `email: {empty}`

Comment: do print_r($data) and see what it returns ?

Comment: print_r($data) return nothing

Comment: meaning if($sql->num_rows > 0){} is not executing !!

Comment: Thanks Abhik Chakraborty, its fixed!!

Comment: cool so what was the issue ?

Comment: incorrectly argument input, by the way, how can it show particular data like `$data->user_email` and so on?

Comment: you are returning an array so you can not use Object you may need to look for converting the array to object before using it as $data->user_email

Comment: it would be great if you can refer me to the tutor link, I am still new in OO.

Comment: http://www.kathirvel.com/php-convert-or-cast-array-to-object-object-to-array/
http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/

Answer (score 3):

`$mysqli` is **never** defined in your code.

You cannot use something that was not defined.